# Could not clone project using SSH Git

Tags: git, ssh, ubuntu-14.04, git-clone

I did as described [here](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/).

When I run:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

I get:

```
Hi my_name! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Then, when I run:

```
ssh-add -l
```

I get:

```
2048 fe:e1:11: ...  /home/my_name/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
```

So it seems to be fine, but when I run this:

```
git clone git@github.com:my_namer/mvc.git
```

I get:

```
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried to check [here](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/) but it didn't help.

Can somebody help me? Thanks!

P.S. Yes I saw related questions, but there is no solution for my problem, I tried these solutions:

Comment: Try without using the ssh-agent first. It will ask you the passphrase when you connect.

Comment: @GHugo, I not use any passphrase

Comment: Do you have read permissions for the repo?

Comment: The error is clearly an authentication error, not a permissions error.  However, given that ssh seems to clearly be authenticating correctly in the first step, I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: What happens if you do `ssh -T git@github` **after** you ran `ssh-add -l` and why do you do that in the first place, since ssh already works correctly without running `ssh-add`